# Very Big NumberPicker

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface, android-fragments

Here is my layout XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroller"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:text="RadioButton" />

                <NumberPicker
                    android:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Here, there is a massive issue here. See the below image to see how big the `NumberPicker` is!

[image]

The `NumberPicker`s I need need is something like below.

[image]

I tried to set the hight and fixed, but seems like it has no much effect. This design is for Phone and Tablet. How can I make this NumberPicker small, as in the image above?

Comment: It seems height of 50dp is not enough for NumberPicker widget. I think you have to write your custom NumberPicker view to fit in such a small area.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
android:scaleX="0.5"
android:scaleY="0.5"
```

and play with the values.

Comment: Thanks. But when scalled, they leave a huge padding

Comment: Yes it will leave a padding, I actually don't know how to scale the whole view not just the picker. I will try to check that.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own custom numberpickerview.or otherwise you can use wheelpicker (same as iphone) that design will be awaysome.